# Build process crashes with boost and C++11

Tags: linux, qt, c++11, boost, crash

What I have:

- I am writing Qt application for Linux (I work in Linx Mint 17.3 64-bit)
- I use C++11 features in my Qt project (Qt ver 5.5)
- I want to add [libslave](https://github.com/Begun/libslave) to my Qt project.
- libslave uses deprecated (for C++11) `boost::function`, `boost::shared_ptr`, `boost::bind` and `boost::any`.

---

My trouble:

When I compile with **gcc** (v the whole project or only library with `-std=c++11` flag boost crashes with many errors. Qt Creator shows about 4000 errors, but they are pretty similar and look like:

1. `typedef boost::function< void( RecordSet& )> callback;
    is not complete type`
2. `BOOST_NOEXCEPT'does not name a type 
                  ~any() BOOST_NOEXCEPT`

etc...

I have tried to rewrite library with C++11 `std` library, but `std` does not containg `boost::any` analog, so that was bad idea.

---

Question:

How to compile boost (or at least libslave) with c++11?

---

Boost Version:   1.54 (from repo)

g++ version:  4.8.4 (from repo)

Qt version:  5.5 (downloaded from Official Site)

Linux Mint:   17.3 Rosa

---

**UPDATE:**

Example:
You can download code what I try to compile by [this link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B79anNNAjGLVTVRldzFsci05TTA).

Instruction:

1. Download tarball
2. Extract
3. Go to folder and just type make (all works fine)
4. Open MakeFile and replace CXX variable to

   CXX = g++ -std=c++11
5. Try to make again and you'll get errors.

P.S.
To compile library you'll need `libmysqld-dev`, `libboost-all-dev`, `libmysqlclient-dev`.

Probably you'll need something else, but I don't remeber. Sorry.

Comment: I'm sorry. First error is "typedef boost::function< void( RecordSet& )> callback; is incomplete type"

Comment: So your program doesn't actually *crash*, instead you have *build errors*? Can you please try to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and show us? Please *edit your question* to include that., as well as the actual (in full and unedited) errors from the MCVE.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg To create example need to complile all library. I've add code what I'm trying to compile to my question. About errors from the MCVE - g++ produce this http://pastebin.com/iU5agusy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the hack and it works for me.

I replace `boost::bind` usage in file **nanomysql.h** to std::bind by such strings:

```
...
typedef std::map<std::string, field> value_t;
typedef std::vector< value_t > result_t;

void store(result_t& out)
{
    //You need specify template because of push_back has overloads
    auto hack = std::bind<void(result_t::*)(const value_t&)>(&result_t::push_back, &out, _1);
    use(hack);
}
...
```

And replace all `boost::shared_ptr`, `boost::function` to `std::shared_ptr` and `std::function` in all files in library.

After this everything compiles and work fine with -`std=c++11` flag.

Whole code of nanomysql.h you can see here:

[Link to code](http://pastebin.com/a376HH8V)

Answer (score 0):

Use actual fork of libslave - https://github.com/vozbu/libslave with support c++11. Support for mysql 5.6 and 5.7 will be soon

Comment: Thanx for link, but it is looks like abandoned repository (last comment was 6 months ago) and I actually need library for 5.6 server version :)